# Java: Casting from List<B> to List<A> when B implements A?

Tags: java, generics, list, inheritance, casting

I have the following class & interface defined:

```
public interface A {
}

public class B implements A {
}
```

I have a `List` of `B` objects that I need to cast to a `List` of `A` objects:

```
List<B> listB = new List<B>();
listB.add(new B());  // dummy data
listB.add(new B());  // dummy data
listB.add(new B()); // dummy data

List<A> listA = (List<A>) listB;
```

The last line above results in compile error "Cannot cast from List<B> to List<A>".  I attempted to work around this with this following instead:

```
List<A> listA = Arrays.asList((A[]) listB.toArray());
```

Unfortunately, that throws a `ClassCastException`.  Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: `new List<B>()` is not valid. `List` is an interface.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot cast it like that. Create a new one:

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>(listB);
```

The constructor takes `Collection<? extends A>`. It will point to the same references anyway.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than fighting against a language feature, you should learn to use it properly.

Rather than asking how to use unsafe casts to work around the error, it is instructive to first understand *why* there's an error; *why* what you're asking to do is unsafe (because you can add an `A` to the list using `listA` and then take it out of the list as a `B` using `listB`).

Then, you should explain *why* you think that your use case does not run into the unsafe scenario. Because the answer to this will give a hint for how to change your code to make it work correctly with generics.

- If you say that it is not unsafe because you never add anything using `listA`, then you should change the type of `listA` to `List<? extends A>`. That way, you can assign `listB` to it directly without any casts, and you won't be able to add anything to it using `listA` (except `null`).
- If you say that it is not unsafe because you never get anything out using `listB`, then why not change the type of `listB` to `List<A>` in the first place?

Comment: This was a long while ago, and I don't even recall what I was trying to do anymore from this question.  But thank you for the feedback, and +1 for language appropriate suggestions.

Comment: At first glance I thought that this would be an arrogant RTFM post, but it turned out to be really insightful and useful. Thank you newacct!

Answer (score 6):

You can just use type erasure if you know the operation is safe.  This produces a warning which you can turn off using @SuppressWarnings

```
List<A> listA = (List) listB;
```

The reason the compiler has difficulty with a plain cast is that you can now add a class C which also implements A.  Except your original list has been altered and now contains a C even though you have specified that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<A> listA = (List<A>)(List<?>) listB;
```

not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you need make the whole list List< A >(weird parsing there) and when adding new B objects cast them with (A)

```
listA.add( (A) new B());  // dummy data
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of declarations. Don't declare listB as List but as List or List.

```
List<A> listB = new List<B>();
listB.add(new B());  // dummy data
listB.add(new B());  // dummy data
listB.add(new B()); // dummy data

List<A> listA = listB;
```

As simple as that.
If you want to force listB to be List (avoiding the addition of any non-B element) you will be forced to use:

```
List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>(listB);
```

But as they already pointed out, if you are forced to do that it is not a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using Generics and Wildcards. You might not be able to create `List<A>` but create something like `List<? extends A>` which will call all the methods of the interface which is enough for most I think.

Creating a new collection is expensive and not advisable. Since the references of the same objects will be passed on into the new collection, the additional list creation step is just an overhead.

```
List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();

List<? extends A> aList = bList;
```