# Java: Compile error assigning Map of a List of an implementation to a Map of a List of a generic type

Tags: java

The code below has been simplified to show my issue:

I have an interface:

```
public interface Cell {
    public String getDescription();
}
```

And I have a concrete class:

```
public class ConcreteCell implements Cell {
    public String getDescription() {
        return "concrete";
    }
}
```

Now I have a data structure that maps a String to a list of Cells:

```
Map<String, List<Cell>> map;
```

This code fails to compile though:

```
map = new HashMap<String, List<ConcreteCell>>();
```

Why is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Casting from List<B> to List<A> when B implements A?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795739/java-casting-from-listb-to-lista-when-b-implements-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine if you use `Map<String, ? extends List<? extends Cell>>`.  The reason for this is that `List<ConcreteCell>` is not a subtype of `List<Cell>`, and then `Map<String, List<ConcreteCell>>` is still not a subtype of `Map<String, List<? extends Cell>>`.

The reason this is true is discussed in many questions on SO, including [Java: Casting from List<B> to List<A> when B implements A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795739/java-casting-from-listb-to-lista-when-b-implements-a) .