# Cast from List<A> to List<B> when B extends A

Tags: java, list, casting, java-8, java-stream

I have two clases:

```
public class A {
   //attibutes and methods
}

public class B extends A {
   //atributes and methods
}
```

Now I have a service that returns a ***List with elements of type A***. Lets call it ***generateAElements()***;

I want to ***call that method***, ***filter the List*** obtained to only ***keep the elements of type B***, which also are of type A.

```
List<A> listA = generateAElements();
List<A> listAA = listA.filter( p -> p instanceof B).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();
// need to create a new list, iterate overListA and add elements of type B?
for (A itemA : listA) {
    listB.add((B) itemA);       
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Important: The list may contain a large number of elements.

Comment: You cannot cast from `List<A>` to `List<B>` because these are not related by inheritance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795739/java-casting-from-listb-to-lista-when-b-implements-a

Comment: See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html

Comment: What is considered efficient?

Comment: To understand **why** this is a problem, see [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: What do you plan to do with your `B` elements that are in `listA`? Do you actually *need* to create a new list or are you going to consume each element of `listA` that is of type `B` in some way?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - this is not a duplicate of that question - the OP is not asking about polymorphic behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you could use streams:

```
List<B> listB = listA
    .stream()
    .filter(B.class::isInstance)
    .map(B.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, this is doable in earlier Java versions, it's just likely to be more verbose.

---

<sub>**A note on terminology:** This is **not** "casting from `List<A>` to `List<B>`" - the only things being cast here are individual entries.</sub>

Comment: TECHNICALLY, it is casting, hence the `::cast`, it's just safe casting because you check compatibility before the cast. Without `::isInstance`, you'd get a cast exception (if there was a non B).

Comment: @Tezra - Ah, yeah, I've clarified what I meant :)

Comment: How is this efficient?

Comment: @JudgeMental - It's hard to see how one could do substantially better than this (short of creating a view, which is kind of cheating!)

Comment: O(N) goes against the spirit of the question.

Comment: @JudgeMental - Assuming one is going to look at the results eventually, one can't do better than O(N).

Answer (score 1):

Stream free version. You just need to do a compatibility check before casting and you are good to do whatever you want.

```
List<A> listA = generateAElements();
List<B> listB = new LinkedList<>();
for (A item : listA) {
    // Skip non compatable items
    if(item instanceof B) 
        listB.add((B) item);       
}
```

The key difference from the OP's code is the line `if(item instanceof B)`, that does the filter/error-checking the OP needed, but didn't do. (This is technically the exact same thing the stream version is doing, but slightly more verbose and much less overhead)

Comment: @PM77-1 The key difference is the line `if(item instanceof B)`, that does the filter/error-checking the OP needed, but didn't do. I also use a LinkList instead of ArrayList for performance reasons (faster inserts).

Comment: Tezra, have you checked that insertions are faster in `LinkedList` than in `ArrayList`? Every time I tested it, `LinkedList` was slower, even for `add`... (BTW, I haven't downvoted your answer)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner ArrayList is faster if you know the size ahead of time, as it can jump to tail index and write. If you exceed ArrayList's buffer (OP said he has large dataset), than you will start to lost to LinkeList as ArrayList has to destroy and reconstruct itself every time you exceed it.

Comment: That's still O(1) amortized, which probably wins out compared to LinkedList's memory fragmentation.

Comment: In my experience, `ArrayList` is *always* faster, no matter the size of the list or if you know the size of the list in advance. Claiming that `X` is faster than `Y` if `Z` condition is always met is a myth. You always have to benchmark for your specific use case with real data in your production hardware. Then, with the evidence at your sight, you can safely come to a conclusion. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Most of the time it just depends on how you will use the list. Most cases will be negligible, and it's just a matter of preference. If it is an issue, you can make an intelligent optimization based on where your issues start arising. (And if you really need that optimization, you definitely don't want to use streams)

Comment: Tezra, I totally agree with you on that. Streams are nice, but they come to a price. If you need performance, go the old imperative way.