# casting from List<B extends A> to List<A> using intermediate wildcard - safe?

Tags: java, casting, unbounded-wildcard

I've noticed following java behavior, which confuse me a little:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().test();
    }

    public void test() {
        List<B> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add(new B());

        // doesn't compile
        // List<A> a = (List<A>) b;
        List<A> a = (List<A>) (List<? extends A>) b;

        System.out.println(a.get(0));
    }

    private static class A {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "A{}";
        }
    }

    private static class B extends A{
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "B{}";
        }
    }

}
```

And it prints `B{}`.

If I have `List<B extends A>` and I want to call a method which expects `List<A>` is it safe or not to do a cast like in the example above?

Why java prohibits `(List<A>)`, but allows `(List<A>) (List<? extends A>)`?

Answer to similar question [Java: Casting from List<B> to List<A> when B implements A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795739/java-casting-from-listb-to-lista-when-b-implements-a) says that "You cannot cast it like that."

My question is - why I was able to cast and what is the consequence of such cast.

Comment: To answer my own question. I think java prohibits `List<B> -> List<A>` cause he knows that `List<B>` is not `List<A>`. Java allows `List<B> -> List<? extends A>` cause `List<B>` is `List<? extends A>`. Java allows `List<? extends A> -> List<A>` cause `List<? extends A>` might be `List<A>`.